# Trying to Write tau = 'τ' out to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write html into a text file and running into problems. At first I couldn't print it but setting up a translate helped,

```
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
```

(found on this site).

It is annoying that printing and writing text can be 'different deals' with Python; here is code that fails:

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: writing tau = 'τ'
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
import os, sys

while True:
    tau = 'τ'
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop")
    dd = open('tmp.txt', 'w')
    dd.write(tau + '\n')
    dd.close()
    sys.exit()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\board.py", line 11, in <module>
    dd.write(tau + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03c4' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to specify an encoding when opening the file. UTF-8 is pretty much always the right choice here.

```
import os

tau = "τ"
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Mike\Desktop")

with open("tmp.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as dd:
    print(tau, file=dd)
```

This is something a lot of people forget when using `open`, but it’s important.

Comment: I researched this for hours and started putting the encode on the write statement with lower case 'utf-8' - it failed.. Anyway it all looks good now!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to specify an encoding when you open your file. From the [`open` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever
>   [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns

If your default system encoding doesn't include the `τ` character, then you will get this error. Try specifying UTF-8. Assuming you are on Python 3:

```
dd = open('tmp.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
```